# Flutter Laravel Push Notifications Android without firebase

Tags: android, laravel, flutter

I am using flutter as frontend and laravel and postgres as my backend. When new data enter database then it should inform laravel and laravel will send response to flutter , flutter must always listen to the response even when the app is closed. How to implement this ? I really need help as I have try looking searching everywhere

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package in your Laravel App [Laravel Echo for Flutter](https://github.com/kakajansh/echo) It helps subscribe to channels and listen for events broadcasted from your Laravel app,

Then install [Pusher Client](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_client) in your flutter app I think if you read each package docs it will help you to configure this out.

Comment: But pusher is not free